# simple form collection - How to display photos but save ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I want to display photos of my instances in my checkboxes but I would like to save only the ID. I don't know where to specify it. This is my actual code (for the moment it is saving the image url) :

```
    = i.input_field :inspiration_image_id, 
     :collection => InspirationImage.all.map {|img| image_tag(img.image.url(:thumb)).html_safe }, 
     :include_blank => '(All)', 
     :multiple => true, 
     :selected => [''], 
     as: :check_boxes
```

I tried to add `value_method: :id` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array of arrays to collection, where first element will be tag and the second will be an id you want `[image_tag, img.id]`

```
:collection => 
  InspirationImage.all.map { |img| [image_tag(img.image.url(:thumb)).html_safe, img.id] }
```